# Lyft Universal Links: Is it possible to set destination location without pickup location?

Tags: lyft-api

Lyft [developers documentation](https://developer.lyft.com/docs/universal-links) states that

> Note that you must set the pickup location if you're setting the destination location.

But it's rather common use case: I know where a user wants to go, but I'd like Lyft to use user's current location as pickup location or ask him to select pickup location itself.

So, is it possible in Lyft Universal Links to set destination location without explicitly setting pickup location?

BTW, Uber has `pickup=my_location` parameter in its Universal Links to handle such situations.

Comment: Starting a bounty on this. I'd like to know if there are any solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the "&pickup[latitude]=&pickup[longitude]=" query parameters then lyft will use the user's location detected when the app (lyft) enters the foreground.  So, yes you can create the link without the pickup location and lyft will grab the location.